# Set datetimepicker years to todays year - 100 range

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I am using the bootstrap datetimepicker to show a date picker and I cannot for the life of me find out how to change the dropdown years to not default to 1950 - 2050.

[image]

I feel I have tried every option people have thrown out there on various website but I think the majority are wrong or are for the JQuery date picker.

Can someone help me out please. Here is what I have now...

```
$('#dob').datetimepicker({
        timepicker:false,
        format:'d/m/Y',
        maxDate: '0',
        disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment(), moment().hour(24).minutes(0).seconds(0)]],
    });
```

Comment: You're looking for minDate() and maxDate();

Comment: Do you mind provided a small example please?

Comment: Do you have the HTML/CSS/JS for what you're trying to do so I can apply it there? You can add a fiddle in your OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, I was looking for one. And I've found a solution and I'm going to share it with you.May you have a good day.

```
var $now  = new Date();
var $year = $now.getFullYear();

$('#dob').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/Y',
    yearStart: $year - 100,
});
```